# I need help to understand the time wich my simple ''hello world'' is taking to execute

Tags: c, performance, time

I've just installed C compilers and everything looks normal, however, when I try to run a code it takes too long. A simple ''hello word'' is taking 12 seconds. An online compiler is doing the same thing in just 2 seconds. I don't know what may be happening

is this normal? Or am I doing something wrong? The only extensions I have are code runner and C/C++

I tried to ignore every other extension or feature, but it continues this way. I can assure my PC is good at least, so I don't think it is the one at fault here. But I don't know

since now, thank you for your help

my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){


printf("hello world");    
return 0;
}                                                                 
 

output: 

hello world
[Done] exited with code=0 in 12.822 seconds
```

Comment: Please post your code and ouptut here as _text_.

Comment: Antivirus or antimalware?

Comment: If you change `printf("foda mano");` to `puts("foda mano");` so that you get a newline after, does that change anything?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: What is the spec of your machine and what OS (Windows/Linux/MacOS/Chromeos,15, 32 or 64 bit) are you running?

Comment: Do you attempt to run the code (i.e. including building the executable first) or attempt to run the executable?